# Start node server without as the application starts

Tags: node.js, react-native, routes

I wish to address an issue that to start the route server, we need to run the command `node routes.js` to start the server. Is there any way to automatically start it as we start the application. 
I am using expo for my react native application.

Comment: For your server, you can use `nodemon`.

Comment: Use `concurrently` package

Comment: Do you want to start your nodejs server application in response to the first start of your client app? You Can't Do That;. The server must already be up and running. You can start your nodejs application when the server boots up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concurrently` installing the NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) module as follow:

`npm install concurrently --save`

You can then edit your package.json:

`"start": "concurrently \"command1 arg\" \"command2 arg\""`

Example:

`"start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"react-scripts start\""`